# Backup/Restore AzureDevOps

Tags: azure-devops

we're using the AzureDevOps Environment from https://dev.azure.com/xxx.
Is the a way to a granualar recovery of deleted elements from boards, repos etc. besides of the recovery of whole projects?

Comment: you'd probably need to do regular backups through api...

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is "it depends". Some things (such as work items) have a "recycle bin" where you can recover them after deletion. Other things (such as board configuration changes) don't.

Source control is, of course, always recoverable as long as the repo still exists -- you can revert changes.

Answer (score 2):

According to our official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/articles/team-services-security-whitepaper?view=azdevops#data-availability) the data is replicated using Azure services such as blob and SQL storage.

However, if you want to have a copy in your own server or local computer, there's no out of the box backup ability.

You could [manually save the project data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/save-project-data?view=azure-devops) through below ways:

- **Source code and custom build templates:** You can download your files as a zip file. Open the Repository actions actions icon for the
  repository, file, or folder and choose Download as Zip. You can also
  choose the Download icon at the right side of the screen to download
  either all of the files in the currently selected folder, or the
  currently selected file.
  This process doesn't save any change history or links to other artifacts.
  If you use Git, clone your repositories to retain the full project history and all the branches.
- **Build data:** To save logs and data in your drop build folders, see View build results.
- **Work item tracking data:** Create a work item query and open it using Excel. Save the Excel spreadsheet.

And for restore, except restore a project, you could also restore a soft-deleted git repo and work items.

[Repositories - Restore Repository From Recycle Bin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/restore%20repository%20from%20recycle%20bin?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)

*Recover a soft-deleted Git repository. Recently deleted repositories go into a soft-delete state for a period of time before they are hard deleted and become unrecoverable.*

[Recovery work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/remove-delete-work-items?view=azure-devops#restore-or-permanently-delete-work-items)

[image]

There has been a related user voice, you could monitor and vote up it

> Provide a backup service for Azure DevOps
>
> *https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/365441/provide-a-backup-service-for-visual-studio-team-se.html*