# How to backup the data on Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to schedule (for my company) a backup of our most important data in Azure DevOps, and that, for different reasons : security, urgent recovery required, virus, migration, etc...

I can execute a backup of the repositories and the Wikis (because it's under GIT, so easy to download), but how can do a backup of the "Board" section (Backlogs, Work items, etc...), and the build pipelines definitions?

Comment: There is no way to do that. You could write your own tool by taking advantages of the REST APIs.

Comment: It is insane that Microsoft doesn't offer anything out of the box that does this.

Answer (score 2):

> How to backup the data on Azure Devops?

In current Azure DevOps, there is no out of the box solution to this. You could manually [save the project data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/save-project-data?view=azure-devops) through below ways:

- **Source code and custom build templates**: You can download your files
  as a zip file. Open `...` Repository actions actions for the
  repository, file, or folder and choose **Download as Zip**. You can
  also **Download** from the right side of the screen to download
  either all of the files in the currently selected folder, or the
  currently selected file.

  [image]

  This process doesn't save any change history or links to other
  artifacts.

  If you use Git, [clone your repositories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/gitquickstart?view=azure-devops) to retain the full project
  history and all the branches.
- **Build data**: To save logs and data in your drop build folders, see
  [View build results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms181733(v=vs.140)).
- **Work item tracking data**: Create a work item query and open it [using
  Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel?view=azure-devops). Save the Excel spreadsheet.

  This process doesn't save any attachments, change history, or links
  to other artifacts.
- **build/release defintions**: you could export the json file for them and then import them when restoring them.

  [image]

There has been a related user voice, you could monitor and vote up it: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/365441/provide-a-backup-service-for-visual-studio-team-se.html.

Here are some tickets([ticket1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55419796/backup-restore-azuredevops) ,[ticket2](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/backup-azure-devops-data/609097)) with the same issue you can refer to.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. When I read some post like that "We were assured by Microsoft that we could restore our projects if they were accidentally deleted. So we deleted the project. It turns out that we had to restore the project due to another issue that occurred. When we came to try to restore it, it turned out we could not as you can only restore an Organization. On top of that the Organization could not be restored to a different name, which would at least allowed us to get the project back. However because none of this was possible, we lost the project", I'm a little bit scared !

Comment: This [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/restore-project?view=azure-devops) is about how to restore deleted projects, you can restore deleted projects through web UI or rest api

Comment: I'll take a look to your document ASAP. Thx

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create scheduled tasks, you can write a script by using the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli) with the [Azure Devops Extension](https://github.com/Azure/azure-devops-cli-extension)

As you said, for the repositories, it's quiet easy as they are Git repositories.

I wrote such a script that we could improve to also backup the Workitems, Backlog, etc...
It's open source, let me know what you would like to backup first and I'll improve it.

Github : [azure-devops-repository-backup](https://github.com/lionelpere/azure-devops-repository-backup)

Comment: This is quite nice. What can the script do as of now? For my use case, I would like to back up code from multiple repos across multiple projects in the same organization, as well as work items and pipelines.

Comment: Only backup code. That's juste a sample of code, not a complete solution.